# Logitech m555b mouse scrolling in OSX 10.7

Tags: macos, scroll

Just updated to Mac Lion (aka OSX 10.7.5) I searched with Goggle for advice on how to revert the "new" (to me anyway) scrolling behavior. (I've decided that needing to be cross functional in Windows and Mac that I will have difficulty learning the "new" convention. The control panels for the Logitech mouse version m555b are *not* the default ones I am seeing in the advice online that allows one to specify that "natural scrolling" will be disabled. Not really a coding question, but does seem to fall within configuring a user interface. If you want to refer me to another venue, please do so. I'll delete the question if advised to do so.

Edit. Since I didn't convey the lack of the desired disable natural scrolling button, I will show the dialog panels I do see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't it the first checkbox, e.g. "Move content in the direction of finger movement when scrolling or navigating"? That seems to be exactly what natural scrolling is.

Comment: Also, I think apple.stackexchange.com or maybe even superuser.com is probably a better fit for this question.

Comment: Thanks @dreamlax: I wasn't aware of apple.stackexchange.com. My next UI question will go there.

Comment: There was an answer of the sort I was expecting: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28730/how-to-i-set-the-scroll-direction-to-be-non-natural-for-any-new-users-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Menu in top left of screen: System Preferences: Mouse: Disable Natural Scrolling
This should work, unless your question was getting at something different.

Comment: Yes. In a beautiful world where everthing ws the same as the defualt setup,  it would, but that pulls up a dialog the does not have the button to which you refer (as I thought I already implied.) I'm thinking I need a Terminal level modification to some plist or another.

Comment: So that checkbox does nothing in the first pic?  Also, you may want to try using the little settings pulldown you see next to the +/- buttons in the bluetooth mouse menu, or see what the advanced button yields.

Comment: Oh. Jeez. How dumb can I be? I was looking for something that said 'natural scrolling'. I guess they changed the description of the option when people didn't know what that meant. Unchecking it does succeed.

Comment: Cool, I was worried that you were having trouble due to the 'hyper-scrolling' feature of the mouse, but yeah Natural Scrolling is one of the strangest features, It makes sense on a track pad with gestures, but not with a mouse. Whod'a thunk?